# Greens theorem but don't know how to start it

Tags: greens-theorem

Evaluate $\oint \limits _C x \space \mathbb d y$ where $C$ is the circle of center $(0,0)$ and radius $4$, taken once anti-clockwise.

How do I start this question? It doesn't look like any of the forms I've seen for Green's theorem before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here $P=0$, $Q=x$. By Green's we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\oint_C xdy=\int\!\!\!\!\int_R\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)dxdy=\int\!\!\!\!\int dxdy=\text{Area of the circle}=4^2\pi=16\pi
\end{eqnarray}